# Linkedin api V2 upload a video in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, linkedin-api

I'm looking for uploading  in node JS a video throught the linkedin API V2 , butI'm still receiving a status code 403. I correctly followed the steps in the documentation. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#register-an-upload-for-video)

```
let req = request(`https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/2125/2125-720.mp4`)
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));

req.on('close', ()=>{
    request({
            url: uploadUrl,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "MY_ID",
                "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms",
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
            },
            encoding: null,
            body: fs.createReadStream('video.mp4')
        }, (error, response, body) => {
                if (error) {
                    cb(error)
                } else {
                    cb({response: response, body: body, url: uploadUrl,})
                }
    });
});
```

It's  working when using the CURL command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#upload-the-video . , but I need to do it in node js.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

finally I found the solution :)

Working code

```
 let req = request(`https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/2125/2125-720.mp4`)
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.mp4'));

req.on('close', ()=>{

    fs.readFile('video.mp4', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var encodedImage = new Buffer(data)

    request({
        url: url,
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "MY_ID",
            "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms",
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
        },
        encoding: null,
        body: encodedImage
    }, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                cb(error)
            } else {
                cb({response: response, body: body, url: url, access_token: access_token, data: ''})
            }
});
```

});
        });